# Why does drawable have a reference to a view?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, reference, drawable, android-view

a very old link about memory leaks talks about a drawable that has a reference to a view ([link here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141113211643/http://www.curious-creature.org:80/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/)) .

i have some simple questions regarding it:

1. why does a drawable have a reference to a view ?
2. what does the drawable do to the view ?
3. does it have a reference to all of the views that use it?
4. do all kinds of drawable have references to views ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading Romain Guy's article too. The website/ blog is now gone, [Wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171116104019/http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/).

Drawable's have a private field (`mCallback`) which refers to an instance of a class which implements the `Drawable.Callback` interface, documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.Callback). View implements this interface, and this callback reference is automatically set by the system when `view.setBackground` is called.

```java
public class View extends Object implements Drawable.Callback, KeyEvent.Callback, AccessibilityEventSource {}
```

**Why set this field?** It's usage is an implementation detail of `Drawable`, so it's difficult to know what exactly its usage is. "The drawable uses this interface to schedule/ execute animation changes." is all I could get from the docs. I guess the main reason is to call `void scheduleDrawable(Drawable, Runnable, TimeToExecuteMeasuredSinceAppLaunch)` [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.Callback#scheduleDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).

> Implement this interface if you want to create an animated drawable that extends Drawable. Upon retrieving a drawable, use Drawable#setCallback(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.Callback) to supply your implementation of the interface to the drawable; it uses this interface to schedule and execute animation changes.

---

So to answer your questions specifically

- **why does a drawable have a reference to a view ?** To call the interface (`scheduleDrawable` and other interface methods) to animate itself. And also, "to schedule and execute animation changes."
- **what does the drawable do to the view ?** The drawable calls those methods in the interface.
- **does it have a reference to all of the views that use it?** The Drawable has 1 callback (so **only 1 view** can be used), and it can set it with `setCallback` documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#setCallback(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.Callback)).
- **do all kinds of drawable have references to views ?** If you set the `setCallback`, yes. It doesn't have to be "animated" to have the reference, because this (`setCallback`) is automatically done with `View.setBackground(Drawable) and ImageView.` according to the [Drawable docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable).

---

Finally, I find his post confusing, as he glossed over this detail which was the fundamental cause of the memory leak (the `Drawable.Callback` interface and more importantly, the `mCallback` field). In the end, the callback in `Drawable` is stored as `private WeakReference<Callback> mCallback = null;`. It is a weak reference which should not cause the memory leak he says. Maybe this was a change to Android after his blog post.

EDIT: Aha! It was Romain who then [changed](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java;bpv=1;bpt=0) it in 2010:

[image: Romain guy's commit details in 2010, stating "Make Drawable.mCallback a WeakReference. "]

Comment: Wow nice. Thank you.

Comment: I liked the question and investigating it was interesting :D

Comment: Yes I was wondering how you got to such an old question.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.why does a drawable have a reference to a view ?

A drawable have a reference to  a View due to allow it the intercept the view state , suppose that you have a selector-drawable that when view mode change in example pressed, focus, disable change it background

Comment: i don't understand . does the drawable has the state of the view ? if so, what happens if the multiple views have the same drawable ?

Comment: they both will be influenced,  for example if you have two imageView with the same selector and one image will changed it state  then also the other image will be reflected from that change!

Comment: i don't understand .do you mean that if i use the exact same drawable using a selector on 2 buttons (for example) and then i touch one of the buttons , the other one will also look as if i've touched it? btw, i mean "does...have".