# Why is the reference to the Context a memory leak?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-leaks

According to [Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/) this kind of code is prone to memory leak due to the fact that

> .... views have a reference to the entire activity and therefore to
>   anything your activity is holding onto; usually the entire View
>   hierarchy and all its resources.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  TextView label = new TextView(this);
  label.setText("Leaks are bad");

  setContentView(label);
}
```

I am not clear about this.
Assuming an application with 1 activity, this is the longest lived object and can be recreated as needed. Which means that all of its instance fields (which can and usually are `View`s) can be null at any time.
And any static instance field will live for the same duration as the activity itself.
So how can we get a memory leak with code like the above or the following:

```
private static Drawable sBackground;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  TextView label = new TextView(this);
  label.setText("Leaks are bad");

  if (sBackground == null) {
    sBackground = getDrawable(R.drawable.large_bitmap);
  }
  label.setBackgroundDrawable(sBackground);

  setContentView(label);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

> Assuming an application with 1 activity, this is the longest lived object

No, it is not. There are other objects in your process (e.g., `Application`, content providers) that will outlive an activity instance.

In particular, note that activities get destroyed and recreated by default on a configuration change (e.g., screen rotation).

> And any static instance field will live for the same duration as the activity itself.

No. Static fields are around as long as the process is around. Your activity instances can be shorter-lived than that.

> So how can we get a memory leak with code like the above or the following:

There is no static field in your first example.

Romain Guy explains the second scenario in [the blog post that you linked to](http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/):

> This code is very fast and also very wrong; it leaks the first activity created upon the first screen orientation change. When a Drawable is attached to a view, the view is set as a callback on the drawable. In the code snippet above, this means the drawable has a reference to the TextView which itself has a reference to the activity (the Context) which in turns has references to pretty much anything (depending on your code.)

And, if you added [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to your project, you would see the leak.

So, let's walk through this:

- User taps on the home screen launcher icon for your app, which is tied to this activity
- Your process is started
- Your activity instance is created, and is then called with `onCreate()`
- `sBackground` is `null`, and so you assign it the `getDrawable()` result
- Your activity UI appears on the screen
- The user sneezes and accidentally rotates the screen of the device as part of reacting to the sneeze
- Your old activity instance is destroyed
- A new activity instance is created, and is then called with `onCreate()`
- `sBackground` **is not `null`**, and so you leave `sBackground` alone

And you have your leak. As Romain explained, `sBackground` has a not-very-obvious reference back to your *original* activity instance. So, now you have two outstanding instances of this activity: the leaked original, plus the new one created due to the configuration change.

Comment: So the first snippet has no memory leak?

Comment: @Jim: Correct. My guess is that it is there to illustrate the sentence immediately preceding the code snippet ("It’s usually the first one that the developer passes to classes and methods that need a Context:"), showing passing a `Context` to the `TextView` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR** This is no longer a memory leak, since 2010. Also, I would have said this was a bug (memory leak) in Android (since this reference was an implementation detail), not in your app. We didn't even know that `setBackgroundDrawable` (deprecated in favor of `setBackground`) calls `setCallback` which sets a strong reference to the `view`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954572/why-does-drawable-have-a-reference-to-a-view/66078037#66078037) I explain why `Drawable` has a reference to `View` anyway.

---

Romain Guy made a fix to the library in **2010** to prevent this from causing a memory leak by using a `WeakReference`, so this hasn't been a problem for many years:

[image]